# XCODE 8 - The entitlements specified in your application's code Signing Entitlements file are invalid

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, xcode8, ios10

I am trying to create a jenkins build for my ios application using gradle.

I have created a adhoc distribution provisioning profile for my application and I am using certificate and password created for a different application in the same team and referencing them in the build.gradle.

Before I create the Jenkins build , I wanted to make sure build is working locally using gradle archive followed by gradle package commands, it worked successfully and created a .ipa file.

When I tried to drag and drop .ipa on my development phone using XCODE window -> Devices , it gave entitlements does not match error. please see below for the screenshot of the issue. I tried everything I can, but It does not fix this issue. Has anyone encountered this before. Please help! if you have , I am using XCODE 8.

The enable capabilities on XCODE
[image: The enable capabilities on XCODE]

The enabled services/entitlements on apple developer website
[image: The enabled services/entitlements on apple developer website]

The below is how my distribution profile looks on the apple developer website
[image: The below is how my distribution profile looks on the apple developer website]

when I package my application and I try to drag and drop the .ipa file using XCODE's window -> Devices. I get the below error.

[image: The screenshot of the exact error]

The below is my entitlements file.

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.developer.healthkit</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

`

Comment: Delete any .entitlements file you have in the xcode if you don't need! Also you need to clear the the code sign entitlements in the build settings.

Comment: when I deleted the .entitlements file, I had to fix issue under HealthKit capability, Xcode recreated the entitlement file for me , I removed the reference for the entitlements file in the code signing entitlements in the build settings, it still didn't fix the issue. I am using openbackery gradle to build the project.